# Should an API return data that has been created or updated?

Tags: json, api

I am crafting my first RESTful API and I am interested in the best practices when crafting an api, let's say I `POST` to my endpoint `/Document/` to create a new `Document`.

What would be a preferred response from the server?

Something that provides just a message indicating the request was successful, or one that indicates a request was successful and here is the information that has been created?

For example:

```
{ message: 'Successfully created document' }
```

Or something along the lines of:

```
{
  message: 'Successfully created document',
  data: {
      id: 123456,
      title: 'hello world',
      body: 'this is the body'
  }
}
```

We could use status codes instead of `message` to indicate whether it was successful (i.e. `204` in the first response, `200` in the second?).

Is there a preferred way to perform these responses? The latter one seems to be more of a 'handshake agreement' versus the first one is more of a 'thumbs up'.

What changes come in when the `Document` is updated, is there more of an argument for sending back the updated `object` or should the format remain the same?

Comment: I think that is entirely up to you. 
An 'API' doesn't float in thin air, it serves the purpose of some 'client'. So, the real design decision is indeed "what does my client do after creating a new document?". If you need some action specific to this document - that require additional data, like the doc ID - then return this additional data.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the status code 201, which means:

201 Created: The request has been fulfilled and resulted in a new resource being created.

I like to return the ID too, so the client can navigate to the document created.

Let messages with the client side. The client gets the status code 201 and decides what message will be displayed.

ref.: [http status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)